# Understanding remote OS detection using Scapy

Tags: network, nmap, tcp, python

I am trying to understand remote OS detection techniques using Scapy. I came across the following article [SANS article on Remote OS detection using Scapy](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/testing/taste-scapy-33249) and have been trying to follow it.

The technique, as I understand from the above, is that if after the initial successful TCP 3 way handshake, if a data packet is sent with flags NOT set to **ACK** , then all the operating systems, except Linux, should respond with a **RST** packet. Linux does not follow this RFC requirement and hence responds back with an **ACK** packet.

This is one way how we can say if it the remote machine is a Linux or any other. There may be other ways of figuring this out as well, but I would like to understand this very technique and what is supposedly going wrong with my scapy script below.

```
from scapy.all import *

seq = 12345
sport = 1040
dport = 80

ip_packet = IP(dst='192.168.56.107')
syn_packet = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='S', seq=seq)

packet = ip_packet/syn_packet
synack_response = sr1(packet)

next_seq = seq + 1
my_ack = synack_response.seq + 1

ack_packet = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=next_seq, ack=my_ack)

send(ip_packet/ack_packet)

payload_packet = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='', seq=next_seq)
payload = "this is a test"
send(ip_packet/payload_packet/payload)
```

In the script above, the machine 192.168.56.107 is a Linux machine running Inetsim and perfectly simulating HTTP among other services. The way I am sure it is working fine is because I am able to successfully do the below:

> nc 192.168.56.107 80

and then send some random data, say the string "abcd" to it. And then when I analyze it with wireshark, it clearly shows that post the TCP 3 way handshake, in response to the "abcd" data packet it sends back an ACK packet.

While if I do the same thing with my script above, and analyze it with Wireshark, the TCP 3 way handshake happens successfully, but post that the server does not respond back with an ACK packet (while it should being a Linux system, which as noted above does not follow the RFC).

What is more strange is that the server does not even respond back with a **RST** packet either.

The linux system is an Ubuntu system, if that makes any difference.

Please help me understand what possibly am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you read the *complication* chapter from your article and try setting `iptables` ?

Comment: Yes. That is taken care of.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you testing against? This works fine on my Ubuntu box, running 17.10